# Connect to Postgres RDS via EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-rds, dbeaver

I want to connect to an Amazon RDS database that is in a private subnet via my EC2 instance.

I have configured the security group for my EC2 machine with an inbound rule for SSH on port 22 and postgresql on port 5432 with all source ip range.

Outbound rule is Postgresql with 5432 and source as RDS security group.

On RDS side, security group is configured as inbound rule of postgresql with EC2 security group.

I am able to SSH into EC2 instance and connect to postgresql well. But when I try to connect via IDE Dbeaver. It always says connection refused.

I want to connect to EC2 instance host with postgres username and password, It should forward to my RDS ideally. Or at least tunneling should work. Which is also not working.

What should be done now?

[image]

I tried all possibilities with which I was able to connect via localhost as SSH into EC2 instance worked and executed:

```
ssh -i sd-private-subnet.pem -f -N -L 5050:rds_endpoint:5432 ec2-user@ec2_public_ip -v
```

When I specify `localhost` in host and port 5050, it gets connected, but I want my EC2 to be host and connect directly to my RDS.

Moreover I have no control over `pg_hba.conf` or `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: "When i specify localhost in host and port 5050, it gets connected, But I want my EC2 to be host and connect directly to my RDS."  You want it to work, but not by doing it in the way that works?

Comment: Yeah, I want to directly use EC2 as a host and just connect from any IDE with the database password and not by localhost. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the database via SSH tunnelling is the correct way to do it.

Make sure you [configure the SSH tunnel in Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/SSH-Configuration/)?

If you want to connect to the database *without* creating a tunnel, then you will need to run something on the EC2 server that redirects requests to the database. However, this will be somewhat insecure since the whole purpose in placing the database in a private subnet is to prevent direct access from the Internet. The SSH tunnel is a way of securing access to the database.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Even if I try connecting via SSH, it says connection refused or Auth fail in SSH tunneling.